# Solved - Is it possible to sort by values and also have some specific values appear first?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I have a table displaying and it is sorting by the first column alphabetically and then by the second if there are any duplicates in the first by using two sorts as below

```
  inventoryData = Object.values(inventoryData).sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.XI_MP_POS < b.XI_MP_POS) { return -1; }
                if (a.XI_MP_POS > b.XI_MP_POS) { return 1; }
                return 0;
            });
            inventoryData = Object.values(inventoryData).sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.XI_MP_DESC < b.XI_MP_DESC) { return -1; }
                if (a.XI_MP_DESC > b.XI_MP_DESC) { return 1; }
                return 0;
            });
```

It's been requested that this sort be maintained but for a few select XI_MP_DESC values to appear at the top regardless of their position alphabetically, is this possible?

I would like to turn for example:

| Desc | POS |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | A |
| C | A |
| C | B |
| C | C |

Into:

| Desc | POS |
| --- | --- |
| C | A |
| C | B |
| C | C |
| A | A |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | A |

By specifying that C always appear at the top

This has been solved using

```
const topDescriptions = ['desc1', 'desc2'];
              inventoryData = Object.values(inventoryData).sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.XI_MP_POS < b.XI_MP_POS) { return -1; }
                if (a.XI_MP_POS > b.XI_MP_POS) { return 1; }
                return 0;
            });
            inventoryData = Object.values(inventoryData).sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.XI_MP_DESC < b.XI_MP_DESC) { return -1; }
                if (a.XI_MP_DESC > b.XI_MP_DESC) { return 1; }
                return 0;
            });
            inventoryData = Object.values(inventoryData).sort((a, b) => {
                const aIsTop = topDescriptions.includes(a.XI_MP_DESC);
                const bIsTop = topDescriptions.includes(b.XI_MP_DESC);
                if (aIsTop && !bIsTop) return -1;
                if (bIsTop && !aIsTop) return 1;
                return 0;
            });
```

Comment: do you have some data and result?

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/mdjyXmz?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for the special order with a default value for unknown items:

- zero for moving to top,
- a large value for moving to bottom,
- any other value for taking a custom sorting.

Inside of the single sorting function sort

- `Desc` by order ascending,
- `Desc` by string ascending.
- `POS` by string ascending.

By using more than one function, the result is only predictable with a stable sorting algorithm.

```js
const
    data = [{ Desc: 'A', POS: 'A' }, { Desc: 'A', POS: 'B' }, { Desc: 'A', POS: 'C' }, { Desc: 'B', POS: 'A' }, { Desc: 'C', POS: 'A' }, { Desc: 'C', POS: 'B' }, { Desc: 'C', POS: 'C' }],
    order = { C: 1, default: Number.MAX_VALUE };

data.sort((a, b) => 
    (order[a.Desc] || order.default) - (order[b.Desc] || order.default) ||
    a.Desc.localeCompare(b.Desc) ||
    a.POS.localeCompare(b.POS)
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a solution now which I have posted in the question :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a third sort after the first two. See the snippet below. I also corrected two mistakes in your snippet: you cannot subtract strings (you'll get a NaN) and you should sort your list in place.

```js
const inventoryData = [
 {XI_MP_POS: 1, XI_MP_DESC: 'aaa'},
 {XI_MP_POS: 4, XI_MP_DESC: 'bbb'},
 {XI_MP_POS: 3, XI_MP_DESC: 'ddd'},
 {XI_MP_POS: 3, XI_MP_DESC: 'ccc'},
];

const topDescriptions = ['bbb', 'aaa'];

inventoryData.sort((a, b) => a.XI_MP_DESC < b.XI_MP_DESC ? -1 : a.XI_MP_DESC > b.XI_MP_DESC ? 1 : 0);
inventoryData.sort((a, b) => a.XI_MP_POS - b.XI_MP_POS);
inventoryData.sort((a, b) => {
  const aIsTop = topDescriptions.includes(a.XI_MP_DESC);
  const bIsTop = topDescriptions.includes(b.XI_MP_DESC);
  if (aIsTop && !bIsTop) return -1;
  if (bIsTop && !aIsTop) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(inventoryData)
```

Comment: Apologies, I had copied an incorrect part from a previous iteration, I'm actually sorting using what is now in the question

Comment: Well, my answer is exactly the same, except that if XI_MP_POS is a string, it should be sorted exactly the same way as XI_MP_DESC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would upvote it but I'm not allowed. Didn't use it exactly as you posted but took from it, have posted the solution in the original question. Really appreciate your help!